# MySQL не добавляются данные запросом

Tags: php, mysql

Впервые работаю с MySQL, написал парсер с помощью библиотеки phpQuery, теперь нужно все это в базу заносить, да не заносится... Через echo выводится всё, а в базу никак не идёт. Никаких ошибок не вылезает. Возможно, что вопрос очень глупый, но никак не пойму, в чём же дело)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASS, DBNAME);
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO horoscope(oven) VALUES($oventodaytext)");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO horoscope(telec) VALUES($telectodaytext)");
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: "через echo выводится всё" - выведите это "всё" и нам тоже)

Comment: все верно... потому что `$oventodaytext` и `$telectodaytext` - у тебя строковые значения.... а их надо как вставлять? в кавычках. Кавычки у тебя явно отсутствуют

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу привыкайте ничего никогда не вклеивать в запрос вручную (расширение mysql устарело не просто так). [Подготавливаете запрос](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php), [связываете параметры](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), [исполняете запрос](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.execute.php).

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASS, DBNAME);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO horoscope(oven) VALUES(?);");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$oventodaytext);
$stmt->execute();
$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO horoscope(telec) VALUES(?);");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$telectodaytext);
$stmt->execute();
$mysqli->close();
```

Далее если это выбор данных (`SELECT`), то [связываете результат](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) и [вытягиваете данные](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает)